# ClojureScript-Lib and my ClojureScript on same page

Tags: javascript, html, google-closure-compiler, clojurescript

Let's assume I have a small web-application and want to use a third-party library that comes with an already compiled version of a ClojureScript.

As a user of that library I have to include that generated Javascript file in my HTML page.

```html
<script src="/javascript/gen/lib.js" type="text/javascript">
```

So far so good. Everything works fine.

But since my web-application needs some frontend-magic, I wanted to include some ClojureScript of my own. So I wrote a couple of lines, compiled it to Javascript and added another line in the HTML head:

```html
<script src="/javascript/gen/lib.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="/javascript/gen/my-stuff.js" type="text/javascript">
```

This is, where it gets ugly. I get this error in the javascript console:

`Error: Namespace "goog.debug.Error" already declared.`

After googling that error, I get multiple pages, that state, that I can not use multiple `Google Closure Compiled` things on one page. See [SO: Multiple ClojureScript files on same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18987333/multiple-clojurescript-files-on-same-page)

So, how do I tackle that situation? On one hand I have an already `Google Closure` compiled lib and on the other hand my ClojureScript stuff. How do I get one (or two) compiled Javascript files out of this?

Would it be easier, if that third-party lib would provide a non-compiled ClojureScript version?

Comment: **Very** interested in this since it would mean that we can't propose `ClojureScript` code without open-sourcing it if the page already uses the closure compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would be easier if the third-party library would provide a non-compiled ClojureScript version. Then you would require it and use it from your code and compile everything together. The ClojureScript compiler with require each dependency once (even the shared dependencies) and the Google Closure compiler would do its optimization pass over all the code.

Try to find the library in Clojars or package it as a jar to consume it from your existing ClojureScript setup. (If the library is open source, give us a link and we'll help you out)